# Unable to load the config file in angular 2

Tags: angular

I have folder structure like below.

```
src
  app
    resources
      config
         home.json
    services
      service.ts
```

I am trying to call the json file from config folder from service.ts like below

```
 return this._http.get('../../resources/config/home.json')
```

And I tried with couple more types. Unable to load the json file.

http://localhost:4200/resources/config/homeConfig.json 404 (Not Found) getting this error

Comment: can you specify more clearly your folder structure? And are you getting any error?

Comment: updated.. please go through it

Answer (score 1):

if your using angular CLI than place inside

> src/assets/home.json

access like this

```
 this.http.get('/assets/home.json')
                .subscribe(res => this.data = res.json());
```

Comment: happy to help. select as best answer